# Error while creating nuxt3 project. Failed to download template from registry

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

When I use this command to create a new Nuxt 3 project:

```
npx nuxi init nuxt-app
```

It outputs this error:

```
 ERROR  (node:1752) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time                         09:53:25
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)


 ERROR  Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed                                                                                  09:53:25

  at /C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/a95e0f536cf9a537/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/init.mjs:13269:11
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async downloadTemplate (/C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/a95e0f536cf9a537/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/init.mjs:13268:20)
  at async Object.invoke (/C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/a95e0f536cf9a537/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/init.mjs:13336:15)
  at async _main (/C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/a95e0f536cf9a537/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)
```

My environments:

- Operating System: Windows 11
- node version : 18.12.0
- npm version: 8.12.1

At first I suspected that this was due to my network. But I didn't get an error when I tried to install other npm packages.

Comment: It should be an issue to the Nuxt github repository, You could look there for a similar problems. Try this `npx nuxi@latest nuxt3-app` not sure if node@18 already is supported in npx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason in [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/8002).

It's indeed a network issue. It couldn't access `raw.githubusercontent.com` from the command line because it couldn't find the corresponding IP address.

After adding the correct ip address of `raw.githubusercontent.com` to the Windows hosts file, the issue was fixed

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered the same error (windows 10). Mine was just plain.

```
ERROR  Error: Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed
```

Yes, it was something related to network or ip being blocked. I managed to solve it though. Here's what I did.

First go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

In this folder look for the 'hosts' file. Open it with notepad as admin. Now in the end of the file (along with other ip addresses) add this line.

```
// Some other ip address
185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Very strange fix, that one should not be needed and is probably not a long term solution IMO. Otherwise, it's mainly a network security bypass and you sysadmin is probably angry now. Still, GG for finding that one out.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue while working at a client (bank), this is mainly a network restriction indeed. They are limiting the access to only a few NPM packages and this one is not whitelisted (mainly the template).

Not sure how to properly bypass it other than manually getting the code with an SSH/HTTP clone or maybe asking them to allow that specific endpoint.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121013/11306308)

Answer (score 1):

A more confidential solution is to set your operating system's DNS server to public DNS server, such as Google(8.8.8.8).

Answer (score 1):

To all the Indians facing this issue, it is a ***JioFiber*** issue. Somehow raw.githubusercontent.com is blocked (for the lack of better word) on JioFiber. I know, weird, but it is what it is.

To all the non-Indians facing this issue, there might be an issue with your internet provider, too. You might as well change the DNS and see if that works.

PS:- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/21853#issuecomment-1765301805

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing your network. Ex :- Mobile network to wifi OR JIO to GTPL (Other Broadband connection).
In my case not working in JIO(Broadband) once we change with GTPL(Broadband) it will installing automatically.

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think for me also it was the issue with JioFiber. I edited the hosts file and added the below line and it worked.

```
185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Answer (score -1):

1.open this file : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2.at the end ,add :185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
3.save it,and the problem should be solved (maybe you don't have the permission).

Comment: Basically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121013/8816585

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).